# Magento 2.2 : How to enable the 'city' field on cart shipping estimator

Tags: shipping, magento2.2

I can see the city field on the file

> => **checkout_cart_index.xml:**

```
<item name="city" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">115</item>
    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.city</item>
    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
</item>
```

but it does not display on the `shipping estimator` on the `cart page`.

Does anyone know how I can get the `City` field on here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am also looking for this solution, i want add city field in Estimate Shipping and Tax in cart view page

Comment: Check this https://webkul.com/blog/enable-city-field-cart-page-magento2/

Comment: this above URL solution is working

Comment: The url solution is working. But the city field is displayed as last. My requirement is to display the city field before the zip

Comment: @JancyAbraham can you please share your solution regarding display the city field before the zip?

Comment: @iqbalmalik I have added the sort order option in the checkout_cart_index.xml
Lowest number is assigned to city field

Comment: please share your solution if you use this in custom module